# How i can prevent parent li's from not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am saving `li` tag id on click event in cookies and then accessing this on next page. But when i click `li` tag its parent `li` tags are also firing so i am not able to get correct `li` id on the next page. menu class is assigned to all `li` tags.

How i can prevent parent `li` to not fire.

```
jQuery('.menu').click(function(){
jQuery.cookie('myCookie', jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need your selector to be more precise.

Comment: There are many elements in my menu and i want to get value of clicked li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the event is bubbling up the DOM. You can stop that by calling `stopPropagation()` on the event argument passed to the handler:

```
$('.menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $.cookie('myCookie', this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a separate class for the ones you use like - cookie-list-element and write a click event handler with this selector